# How to add weighted for KNN?

Tags: python, knn

I just learned about Machine Learning. I wrote a piece of code about KNN but I can't add weight = 1/distances in my code. Can anyone help me, please?
Thank you very much!
I'm sorry about the wording because I used GG translate
Below is the code I have referenced:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
class KNearestNeighbor():
      def __init__(self , k):
          self.k = k 
          
      def train(self,X,y):
          self.X_train = X 
          self.y_train = y
  
      def predict(self,X_test):
          distances= self.euclidean_distance(X_test)
          return self.predict_labels(distances)
           
      def euclidean_distance(self,X_test):
          num_test = X_test.shape[0]
          num_train= self.X_train.shape[0]
          distances= np.zeros((num_test,num_train))
          for i in range(num_test):
            for j in range(num_train):
              distances[i,j]= np.sqrt( np.sum((X_test[i,:] - self.X_train[j,:])**2)) 
          return distances
  
      def predict_labels(self,distances):
          num_test= distances.shape[0]
          y_pred= np.zeros(num_test)
          for i in range(num_test):
              y_indices= np.argsort(distances[i,:])
              k_closet_classes= self.y_train[y_indices[: self.k]].astype(int)
              y_pred[i]= np.argmax(np.bincount(k_closet_classes))
          
          return y_pred
if __name__ == '__main__':
     iris = datasets.load_iris()
     X = iris.data
     y = iris.target    
     X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
     X, y, test_size=0.2,random_state=2)
     KNN = KNearestNeighbor(k=10)
     KNN.train(X_train,y_train)
     y_pred = KNN.predict(X_test)
     print(f'Accuracy: {sum(y_pred == y_test )/y_test.shape[0]}')
```